# Como carregar arquivos css de maneira assíncrona?

Tags: javascript, css, otimização, pagespeed-insights

Bom, coloquei o o link do meu site, para ser analisado no [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) e para corrigir questões otimização e etc..
E para o `javascript`, foi apontado que precisava ser corrigido

> **Eliminar JavaScript e CSS de bloqueio de renderização**

E que solucionei fazendo conforme este [site](http://lorindo.com/adiar-a-analise-de-javascript-carregando-scripts-de-forma-assincrona/), fazendo da seguinte forma, na hora de chamar o arquivo js

```
<script async defer  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Porém o mesmo erro é apontado para arquivos css. Existe uma maneira semelhante para carregar arquivos css de maneira assíncrona?